# Break line within a macro while writing to a file

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, programming, fancyvrb

I am trying to use (La)TeX as a macro pre-processor for a programming language. My idea is to use the `VerbatimOut` environment from the `fancyvrb` package to output essentially verbatim text, but using `@` as an escape character to introduce a macro.  Here's an example of the sort of thing I have in mind:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\def\definesortfunction #1;{%
#1[] sort(#1[]  a) {
    if (a.length <= 1) return a; 
    static #1[] merge(#1[] b, #1[] c) { 
        #1[] toreturn;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < b.length && j < c.length) {
            if (!(c[j] < b[i])) { toreturn.push(b[i]); ++i; }
            else { toreturn.push(c[j]); ++j; }
        }
        while (i < b.length) {
            toreturn.push(b[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        while (j < c.length) {
            toreturn.push(c[j]);
            ++j;
        }
        return toreturn;
    }
    int halfway = floor(a.length / 2);
    #1[] b = sort(a[0:halfway]);
    #1[] c = sort(a[halfway:a.length]);



    return merge(b, c);
}}

\begin{VerbatimOut}[commandchars=@\#~]{testoutputfile.asy}
bool operator <(pair a, pair b) {
    return (a.x < b.x  || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y));

@definesortfunction pair;
\end{VerbatimOut}

\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput{testoutputfile.asy}
\end{document}
```

The resulting file works well as far as the Asymptote compiler is concerned. The problem is that the Asymptote source file is virtually unreadable (to humans) because the entire macro gets typeset on one line—including the line that was originally preceeded by three distinct line breaks.

By playing with active characters, I have been able to replace the line breaks by the letters `^^M` or `\par` (both of which break the Asymptote compiler), but I have not found a way to replace them with actual line breaks.  How can I do this?

(Note that I am in no way wedded to the `fancyvrb` package; anything verbatim file-output environment with custom escapes would satisfy me, including one created on the spot. But since TeX code shows up sometimes in Asymptote files, being able to customize the escape characters is essential.)

Comment: Are you going to use `\definesortfunction` in other places, or only in the context of `VerbatimOut`?

Comment: @egreg: Only in the context of `VerbatimOut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the macro just for substituting in the `VerbatimOut` environment, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begingroup
\endlinechar=`^^J \obeyspaces% end of lines are newlines
\gdef\definesortfunction #1;{% eat up the space following the macro
#1[] sort(#1[]  a) {
    if (a.length <= 1) return a; 
    static #1[] merge(#1[] b, #1[] c) { 
        #1[] toreturn;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < b.length && j < c.length) {
            if (!(c[j] < b[i])) { toreturn.push(b[i]); ++i; }
            else { toreturn.push(c[j]); ++j; }
        }
        while (i < b.length) {
            toreturn.push(b[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        while (j < c.length) {
            toreturn.push(c[j]);
            ++j;
        }
        return toreturn;
    }
    int halfway = floor(a.length / 2);
    #1[] b = sort(a[0:halfway]);
    #1[] c = sort(a[halfway:a.length]);



    return merge(b, c);
}% this % is necessary
}% this % is necessary
\endgroup% this % is necessary

\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}[commandchars=@\#~]{testoutputfile.asy}
bool operator <(pair a, pair b) {
    return (a.x < b.x  || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y));

@definesortfunction pair;
\end{VerbatimOut}

\VerbatimInput{testoutputfile.asy}
\end{document}
```

Here's the listing of `testoutputfile.asy`:

```
bool operator <(pair a, pair b) {
    return (a.x < b.x  || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y));

pair[] sort(pair[]  a) {
    if (a.length <= 1) return a;
    static pair[] merge(pair[] b, pair[] c) {
        pair[] toreturn;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < b.length && j < c.length) {
            if (!(c[j] < b[i])) { toreturn.push(b[i]); ++i; }
            else { toreturn.push(c[j]); ++j; }
        }
        while (i < b.length) {
            toreturn.push(b[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        while (j < c.length) {
            toreturn.push(c[j]);
            ++j;
        }
        return toreturn;
    }
    int halfway = floor(a.length / 2);
    pair[] b = sort(a[0:halfway]);
    pair[] c = sort(a[halfway:a.length]);



    return merge(b, c);
}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: This is great! One minor caveat: Tabs get ignored. (Also, it might be nice to have a macro for defining macros this way, but I'm not sure that's possible and this definitely solves the problem that was bugging me.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Writing tabs in files is always a pain. For a generic macro, I'll study the problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only reason I have not already accepted your answer is that I always wait a day before doing so in case something unforeseen gets pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is something similar to the attempt achieved by various 'problem-solution' packages available for `LaTeX`, where the solution of a problem is typeset, not expanded and ten written verbatim to another file to be included at some other position.

Your approach is to expand first the macros, then write them verbatim to a programming language source code file?

In my opinion it is worth to have a look on the `tcolorbox` package -- it does have such a feature, and your are not interested in the `LaTeX` output itself, there is no need to worry about colorboxes.